# Run-time error '429' Active X component can't create object. Code no longer working after upgrading to windows 10 from windows 7

Tags: excel, vba

I have set up an automated email macro using excel VBA referencing outlook on windows 7. I have since upgraded to windows 10 and receive the error listed in the title when running on my new application. I have tried a number of things displayed in previous threads but cannot solve the issue.

I have tried using the early binding method:

`Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`

instead try:

`Set objOutlook = New Outlook.Application`

but this does not work.

The code is the following:

```
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object

Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.createitem(0)
```

Comment: I`m not getting any error running your code (win 10, latest office version).

Comment: Try running the code line by line in debug mode. If it runs successfully then the issue is one of timing and you probably need a DoEvents commands in-between the two Set statements.

Comment: Are you using a Button to run this Macro ?

Comment: Hi, I am not using a button and in debug mode it falls over at the set outlookapp= createobject("Outllok.Application"). That is when the error appears.

Comment: What version of Office?

Comment: Office and outlook 2016

Comment: Just curious, was the office version changed during upgrade?

Comment: `Dim outlookapp As Outlook.Application` and `Dim outlookmailitem As Outlook.MailItem`... Just a guess (it's more specific), It's hard since I can't reproduce issue.

Comment: The office version has remained the same- still using 2016. The 'Dim outlook app as Outlook.Application' returned an error of "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined"

Comment: To update, I have found out that after the update, excel remained as office 2016 but it upgraded to a 64bit from 32bit. Still no resolution